# Add a django-filter to allow contains, match (exact) and exclude certain text

Tags: django-rest-framework, django-filter, django-viewsets

Based on the documentation for [django-filters](https://django-filter.readthedocs.io/en/stable/ref/filterset.html#declaring-filterable-fields) to use [excludes](https://django-filter.readthedocs.io/en/stable/ref/filters.html#exclude) I have a filter that allows custom filtering for **multiple** fields to search to match text (`exact` or `contains`).
I'm trying to extend this to allow the text to be excluded from the search. i.e search for columns **NOT** containing text.

This is not what I want to do, I want the filter to essentially work like:

```
Table.filter(col1__contains='text', col2='text2').exclude(col3='text3')
```

Similar to but need an example that works for exact, matching and exclusive searches.
[How to use Django filter's exclude argument with user input?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58702254/how-to-use-django-filters-exclude-argument-with-user-input)

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to use a custom filter method:

- https://django-filter.readthedocs.io/en/stable/ref/filters.html#method.

```py
class MyFilter(FilterSet):
    text = CharFilter(method='filter_published')

    def filter_published(self, queryset, name, value):
        return queryset.fitler(col1__exact=value).exclude(col3__contains=value)

    class Meta:
        model = Book
        fields = ['published']
```

You can also wrap it all up in a custom filter field if you intended to re-use it, something like this (untested):

```py
class FancyCharFilter(CharFilter):
    def __init__(include_fields, exclude_fields): 
        self.include_fields = include_fields
        self.exclude_fields = exclude_fields

    def filter(self, queryset, name, value):
        for field in self.include_fields:
            queryset = queryset.filter(**{field: value})
        for field in self.exclude_fields:
            queryset = queryset.exclude(**{field: value})
        return queryset
        
class MyFilter(BaseFilter):
    text = FancyCharFilter(
        include_fields=["col1__exact", "col2__contains"],
        exclude_fields=["col3__contains"]
    )
```

Comment: Thanks. I think I might need to edit this to exclude for filters containing text, not an exact match to be excluded.